# Submit values from partial view to parent viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

Lets say I have a partial view that contains both a checkbox and a numerical value.
I have a ViewModel that contains a Model -- Terms --  that implements the partial view. When I submit it, the modifications made in the Terms Partial View does not reflect to the Terms property of ViewModel. I'm probably misunderstanding a concept or another on how it works, anyone care to point it out please?

**View**

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewAction", "ViewController", FormMethod.Post))
{
 // Other ViewModel Property Editors

 @Html.Partial("Terms", Model.Terms)
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model Terms

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsAccepted)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NumericalValue)
```

**Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult ViewAction(int id)
{
 ViewModel vm = GetVmValues();
 return View(vm);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ViewAction(ViewModel vm)
{
 // Access ViewModel properties
}
```

Comment: That should work work - I don't think you have misunderstood the concept.  I have essentially the same thing working (although I used `@RenderPartial(..)` instead of `@Partial(..)` but that shouldn't make any difference).  Can you share some more code?

Comment: Really? That's basically my code after trimming out all the other cosmetic markup. It's actually weird because I am also losing the values of the ViewModel and the vm value being passed to the Post action is a new instance of ViewModel with default value.

Comment: Have a look at the input boxes IDs using your web browsers "developer tools" - the ID should look like "Terms_NumericalValue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default model binder expects the control ids for your Terms model to be named `Terms.IsAccepted` and `Terms.NumericalValue`. You need to create an editor template for your `Terms` model and then call `@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Terms)` instead of using a partial.

You can read more about editor templates [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html). Its from MVC 2, but should still be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Change the model type of your Partial View to 'ViewModel' instead of 'Terms'.
Here is the updated code:

View:

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewAction", "ViewController", FormMethod.Post))
{
 // Other ViewModel Property Editors

 @Html.Partial("Terms", Model)  //Set parent 'ViewModel' as model of the partial view
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model ViewModel

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Terms.IsAccepted)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Terms.NumericalValue)
```

The generated Html will be:

```
<input id="Terms_IsAccepted" name="Terms.IsAccepted" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

While the [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx) map values from value providers (e.g. form data/route data/query-stirng/http file) to a complex object, it searches values having the name as the properties of the object. In your case, to build the 'Terms' child object of your 'ViewModel', it will search for values with the names like 'Terms.IsAccepted', 'Terms.NumericalValue' etc.
The Html helper uses the property path expression to generate the html element's name, that is why you have to use the parent ViewModel as model of the partial view.

Hope this helps...